# v-on:keyup.enter and v-on:keydown.tab ... inside form, listening on <input/>

Tags: vue.js

I have the following form `<input/>`:

```
<form>
    ...
    <input
        id="tags"
        class="w-full h-full rounded-lg py-2 pl-2 pr-4 block w-full appearance-none leading-normal transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"
        v-bind:value="tag"
        v-on:input="processTags($event.target.value)"
        v-on:keydown.enter.tab="processTags($event.target.value)"
    />
</form>
```

However, on hitting tab - nothing happens (expected if `v-on:keyup:tab` removed). And on enter, the page reloads (expected if `v-on:keyup:enter` removed).

What is the correct way to listen to multiple events on one input?

I have trawled the forums and Stack Overflow for a suitable answer - but every answer I have read uses what I am doing. Perhaps the issue is not using `v-model=""` instead of the `v-bind:value=` and `v-on:input=` verbose method. (I need this to stay, as I need to modify the users input).

Comment: Code works fine for me. Event is triggered for enter + tab key separately, and also on input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
    <input
        id="tags"
        class="w-full h-full rounded-lg py-2 pl-2 pr-4 block w-full appearance-none leading-normal transition duration-150 ease-in-out sm:text-sm sm:leading-5"
        v-bind:value="tag"
        @input="processTags($event.target.value)"
        @keydown.enter.prevent="processTags($event.target.value)" // need to prevent the default action
        @keydown.tab.prevent="processTags($event.target.value)"
    />
```

If you do @keydown.enter.tab that would be enter and tab at the same time, like ctrl tab or something

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Balazs, that is exactly it - I think I wasn't using the .prevent tag - I also believe I was getting confused as my logic inside the `processTags` handler was preventing anything from actually being done! D'oh! Thank you nonetheless, accepted answer and upvoted!

Comment: Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

> on enter, the page reloads (expected if v-on:keyup:enter removed).

To fix this issue you can prevent default form submit behaviour like

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="noop">
```

as a form is submitted by default on enter on any element inside form tag.

DEMO:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#myApp',
  data: { tag: '' },
  methods: {
    processTags: function(value) {
      console.log(value)
    },
    noop() {}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="myApp" style="padding:2rem;">
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="noop">
    <input type="text" 
      :value="tag" 
      @input="processTags($event.target.value)" 
      @keydown.enter.tab="processTags($event.target.value)" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, in this demo you can see tab is working fine. But you will notice it only works on the first tab, as after the first tab the focus is lost from the input. You can simply click inside the input again and the tab event will work again and so on..

Comment: Hi Palash, thank you for your considered answer. I was halfway to implementing the first answer before I gave yours a shot - but I see it also works, so I have upvoted but unfortunately I could only accept the first answer! :) Thank you again.